# By using count function i want to know one user has how many no .of rolls?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select pu.username, prdt.role_name, prdt.description, prd.role_common_name 
from   per_users pu, per_user_roles pur, per_roles_dn prd, per_roles_dn_tl prdt
where  pu.user_id = pur.user_id
and    pur.role_id = prd.role_id
and    prd.role_id = prdt.role_id
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0):

When all we know is a query that (probably) fetches some data we don't know, **maybe** it is just the `count` function with appropriate `group by` clause that answers your question. Also, although not related to this problem, `JOIN`s instead of comma-separated tables in the `from` clause.

```
SELECT pu.username,
       prdt.role_name,
       prdt.description,
       prd.role_common_name,
       COUNT(*)cnt                         --> this
FROM per_users pu
JOIN per_user_roles   pur  ON pur.user_id  = pu.user_id
JOIN per_roles_dn     prd  ON prd.role_in  = pur.role_id
JOIN per_roles_dn_tl  prdt ON prdt.role_in = prd.role_in
GROUP BY pu.username,                      --> and this
         prdt.role_name,
         prdt.description,
         prd.role_common_name
```